# Como faço um script de backup incremental em um banco de dados postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, backup

Gostaria de saber como faço um script .sp1 para fazer um backup incremental diário?

Gratidão!

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/continuous-archiving.html

Comment: Deixei o comando `SELECT pg_start_backup('label', true);` rodando por mais de 24h e não finalizou. Isso é correto?